# Is it possible to move arrow span out of the default parent container in jssor?

Tags: javascript, jssor

Is it possible to move arrow span

```
<span u="arrowright" class="jssora13r" style="height: 50px;
    margin-right: -480px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 200px;
    width: 50px;">
</span>
```

outside of the `div#slider1_container` container to any other part of the page?

Btw I tried to specify

```
$ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: 'myOwnCssClass',
    ...
}
```

and it doesn't work for me ((

Upd from comment:

In examples I've found arrows are in the slider container (like [this](http://i.gyazo.com/3cf1a3cc275a37d04289d82722611f05.png)). When I'm trying move it outside, e.g. to root of the 'body' buttons are shown but no reaction on click :( For my layout I must move it to root to implement my customization.

Comment: The $Class is for javascript class, it is not for css class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow is already outside of 'slides' container.

You can arrange layout and adjust size manually.

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-arrange-layout-adjust-size.html

**Edit**:

I was thinking that you can make the 'slider1_container' bigger to achieve your goal.

And now, please note that when you move the arrow outside, it is no longer a part of jssor slider. You have to detect click on the arrow, and then call api to make jssor slider slide left<->right.

```
function OnArrowLeftClick() {
    jssor_slider1.$Prev();
}

function OnArrowRightClick() {
    jssor_slider1.$Next();
}
```

Comment: In examples I've found arrows are in the slider container (like [this](http://i.gyazo.com/3cf1a3cc275a37d04289d82722611f05.png)). When I'm trying move it outside, e.g. to root of the 'body' buttons are shown but no reaction on click :(

For my layout I must move it to root to implement my customization.